# How to required a date input field when checkbox checked is true in react hook form?

Tags: reactjs, validation, checkbox, conditional-formatting, react-hook-form

Suppose i have a checkbox , it's not a required field. if user checked it a date input field will be shown. and date field is required  and date must be a past date. if user unchecked the checkbox , date field will not be a required field. and no error will be shown when user submit the form . and form will be submitted . I am using react-hook-form  version "^7.43.9" .

```
I have tried to do this like this. it's working fine but it's givinig me initially error when  i give defaultValue="" and it's giving me date field is required when I checked the checkbox then did not select any date and unchecked the checkbox. Where as i want date field will be required only when checkbox is checked true, if user unchecked checkbox , date will be not required.


const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  roofDate: yup
    .date()
    .typeError("Please enter a valid date")
    .max(
      new Date(Date.now() - 86400000),
      "Date can not be future or current date"
    )
    .when("roofCheck", {
      is: true,
      then: yup.date().required("Roof date is required"),
    })})

                  <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div className="mb-3">
                      <label className="brand-label d-grid">
                        <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                          <input
                            className="form-check-input"
                            type="checkbox"
                            id="roofCheck"
                            name="roofCheck"
                            value="Roof"
                            {...register("roofCheck")}
                          />
                          <label
                            className="form-check-label"
                            htmlFor="roofCheck"
                          >
                            Is Roof Updated?
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </label>

                      {watch("roofCheck") && (
                        <>
                          <input
                            type="date"
                            id="roofDate"
                            className="form-control"
                            rules={{ required: "Date is required" }}
                            placeholder="Enter Roof Date"
                            {...register("roofDate")}
                          />
                        </>
                      )}
                      {errors.roofDate && (
                        <p className="text-danger">
                          {errors.roofDate?.message}
                        </p>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired behavior where the date field is only required when the checkbox is checked, you need to make a few adjustments to your code. Specifically, you should conditionally apply the validation rules based on the state of the checkbox. Here's how you can do it using React Hook Form and Yup:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";

const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  roofDate: yup.date()
    .typeError("Please enter a valid date")
    .max(new Date(Date.now() - 86400000), "Date cannot be future or current date"),
  roofCheck: yup.boolean(),
});

function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, control, errors, watch } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label className="brand-label d-grid">
            <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
              <Controller
                name="roofCheck"
                control={control}
                defaultValue={false} // Set the default value to false
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <input
                    className="form-check-input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    {...field}
                  />
                )}
              />
              <label className="form-check-label">Is Roof Updated?</label>
            </div>
          </label>

          {watch("roofCheck") && (
            <>
              <Controller
                name="roofDate"
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <input
                    type="date"
                    id="roofDate"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter Roof Date"
                    {...field}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </>
          )}

          {errors?.roofDate && (
            <p className="text-danger">{errors.roofDate.message}</p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Key points to note:

I've added Controller components to manage the checkbox and date input fields. This allows you to control the behavior of these fields within the form.

I set the default value of roofCheck to false, so initially, the checkbox will be unchecked, and the date field won't be required.

The validation schema is now based on the checkbox state. If the checkbox is checked (roofCheck is true), the roofDate field is subject to validation. If it's unchecked, the roofDate field is not required.

With these adjustments, the date field will only be required when the checkbox is checked, and you won't encounter the initial error when the form loads.

Comment: but it's not showing initial date field required text. i wan to show date field is required  error when user checked the checkbox but not selected any date and want to submit the form. and when i checked the checkbox but did not selected any date or removed the selected date and unchecked the checkbox it's showing me error date can not be null or something